# Are the chunk sizes in an HTTP response with "Transfer-Encoding: chunked", significant to protocols that sit on top of HTTP?

Tags: http, rpc, chunked-encoding

Does anything carried inside HTTP care about chunk sizes?  Some sort of RPC protocol perhaps?

**EDIT:** Here's the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) sample response

```
Date: Mon, 30 Mar 2009 22:22:21 GMT

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

23
This is the data in the first chunk

1A
and this is the second one

0
```

The response could have easily been chopped up into chunks of sizes different from 23 and 1A.  Is there a case where chunk boundaries may be significant?

Comment: Is there ay other way on the clinet side to make sure it received all the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None that I know of. It would be against the spirit of HTTP if not an outright bug.

Comment: That makes sense I guess.  I suppose it is conceivable that chunk boundaries may be used to delimit some higher level protocol, but it would require both sides to agree.

Comment: Yeah, a protocol could in theory do that, but it'd be pretty bogus since the usual purpose of layering things over HTTP is to abstract this stuff away. I would be surprised if this actually happened (other than unintentionally due to poor implementation).